# iCarousel iCarouselTypeRotary item views leave copy in background

Tags: ios, cocoa, icarousel

when using iCarousel with iCarouselTypeRotary style, it all seems to work well except that a copy of the intial view always sits in the background (as if there were an additional iCarousel behind the first one that doesnt respond to events)

Curiously enough this doesnt happen the first time the app is run on a device. Perhaps this has something to do with setting the view items imageView's image with SDWebImage - as this is the only thing I can imagine making any difference of this sort.

Any suggestions welcome

Thanks

Tudor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most likely explanation is that it's exactly what it looks like - you are somehow adding multiple copies of the carousel to your view.

Are you adding the carousel programatically in the viewDidAppear method? And if so, do you check if it already exists, or remove the old one if it does?

Try setting a breakpoint to see how many times the code to add the carousel is executed.

Comment: Nick you are right. Noticed this morning that an extra callback was happening and I wasn't checking to see if the iCarousel object was nil before allocing.  Anyway good opportunity to thank you for such a great library - Thanks